# How do I install LINE messenger in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

After few hours of trying, I registered here to ask you.. I want to install Line messenger on my Ubuntu 12.4. Among other things, I tried to do this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFAToIc4fF0

But it just doesn't work. Is there any way that Line works in Ubuntu, or I really have to switch to Windows because of this :/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't watched your video, but last I tried, it worked in Wine. (However, ibus doesn't work well with Wine applications, so you can't use it to type Japanese, if that's what you want to use it for.)

Comment: Well I don't need Japanese, but I don't know how to make it work in Wine really. I open Wine and browse the exe file, I click "apply", and nothing happens :/

Comment: Have you tried the good ol' `wine file.exe`?

Comment: Yes I have.. nothing